# Why some events don't get raised when mocking WCF with Moq?

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have a code that looks like this:

```
mockSecurityService
    .Setup(s => s.CreateUserWithRolesAsync(
        It.IsAny<MembershipRoles>(),
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<MembershipCreateStatus>()))
    .Raises(p => p.CreateUserWithRolesCompleted += null,
        new CreateUserWithRolesCompletedEventArgs(new object[] { mr },
            null, false, null)
    );
```

But when the `CreateUserWithRolesAsync()` gets called, the event in Moq doesnt get raised. Any idea why? I looked through much documentation, and it should be raised, because the signatures match (`It.IsAny<T>` matches all types correctly).

Comment: Can you post your test code (eg. how you subscribe/call it in test method)? The way you setup mock seems to be correct, which would mean problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me, that you have to different signatures of the method `CreateUserWithRolesAsync`. So the call `CreateUserWithRolesAsync()` will not match the setup for the call with three parameters.

To help you furthermore you need to post all different signatures of `CreateUserWithRolesAsync` and the test which is not working.